# Why I'm getting std::bad_variant_access with std::variant?

Tags: c++, c++17, ubuntu-18.04, variant, gcc7

Consider:

```
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double foo = 666.666;
    std::variant<double, uint64_t> v = foo;
    std::cout << std::get<uint64_t>(v) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This results in:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_variant_access'
  what():  Unexpected index
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Why?

I have understood that `std::variant` would be a replacement for `union`. But if this kind of basic stuff fails what is it good for?

Comment: `union` was never good for type punning. It is always Undefined Behaviour to read different union member than last written one.

Comment: You don't have a `uint64_t` in the variant.  Why do you expect it to give you one?

Comment: You assign it a double and read it as an integer. What did you expect? Doing this with a union enters UB land so getting an exception instead is exceptionally better.

Comment: Also note that type punning though a union in C++ is illegal except if the union has standard layout classes in it that have a shared initial common member sequence and you only access that shared sequence.

Comment: @NathanOliver doesn't that violate strict aliasing?

Comment: `std::variant` is a good replacement for `union` and the fact that is fails here is is an example of why it's a good replacement. You aren't allowed to do that with a `union` but at least with `std::variant` it tells you that you are making a mistake.

Comment: @Timo Not for that specific case.  See paragraphs 21-25 here: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class#mem-21

Comment: It seems that there's no way to simply reinterpret double as uint64_t without compiler warnings about strict aliasing or resulting in UB. Good times.

Comment: @juzzlin If that is what you want to do, then the C++ way to do that is to `memcpy` the double into a uint64_t.

Comment: With C++20 you can use [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast).

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the tip :) Didn't think of that route..

Comment: "But if this kind of basic stuff fails what is it good for?" I would consider this a strong example of the basic stuff succeeding :-)

Comment: It also seems that I failed hard reading the documentation..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have understood that std::variant would be a replacement for union.

Yes. Kind of. But your misunderstanding seems to be with unions in C++. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union):

> It's undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written. Many compilers implement, as a non-standard language extension, the ability to read inactive members of a union.

Note that this is different from C, which is one root cause of a common misunderstanding that accessing an inactive member would also be allowed in C++.

> Why?

Because `std::variant` mimics unions but add some safety and [`std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get) is...

> Index-based value accessor: If v.index() == I, returns a reference to the value stored in v. **Otherwise, throws std::bad_variant_access.** The call is ill-formed if I is not a valid index in the variant.

.

> But if this kind of basic stuff fails what is it good for?

Unions in C++ were never meant to be used like that. Unions are rather to save memory when you want to squeeze two or more values into the same memory (but at any time only use one of them). I never met a real use case for them. `std::variant` however, is a nice addition to C++ types. The bigger picture is that already since long time there were so-called product types, like `std::pair<T1,T2>`, in the sense that the set of values they can represent is `T1 x T2`. With `std::variant` (and `std::any`) now C++ also has proper (= with a degree of typesafety that you never got from unions) sum types, ie the set of values a `std::variant<T1,T2>` can represent is `T1 + T2` (sorry for using sloppy notation, hope it is clear).

Answer (score 1):

`std::variant` is a “type-safe union”, meaning it’ll check that what you get from it is the type that is last stored in it.  In this example you are storing a `double` but trying to get an `uint64_t`.

See the docs here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get

> Type-based value accessor: If v holds the alternative T, returns a reference to the value stored in v. Otherwise, throws std::bad_variant_access. The call is ill-formed if T is not a unique element of Types....